# How can I reload slider when I toggle between slide/fade?

Tags: jquery, bxslider

Please note: **I can't show a working example**, this only functions inside my CMS however I will do my best to explain.

In the CMS, client side, I have a dropdown, the value toggles the slider from slide to fade **data.config.dropdown1**.
This dropdown selection changes the slider in real time however making the change for some reason breaks the sliders appearance.

My question is how can I reload the slider every time someone makes a selection, below is my best shot at it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var switch = data.config.dropdown1;
  
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: switch,
    auto: true,
    speed: 1000,
    pause: 6000,
    nextText: '<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>',
    prevText: '<i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>'
  });
  
  switch.reloadSlider();
});
```

Again I am sorry I cant provide a working version but it only works in the client editing section of my CMS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions here, since you haven't provided any HTML, but I'd probably just create a simple change handler for the select element and re-initialize bxSlider from that.

Note that `switch` is a reserved word in JavaScript. Don't use it to name values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const switchEl = data.config.dropdown1; // select element

  function initSlider() {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      mode: switchEl.value,
      auto: true,
      speed: 1000,
      pause: 6000,
      nextText: '<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>',
      prevText: '<i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>'
    });
  }
  
  initSlider();
  $(switchEl).change(initSlider);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, sorry I know its a vague and a long shot but I need to reload the slider once the value changes, I think we need to reload the slider using the slider option https://bxslider.com/options/ "reloadSlider".

Comment: Feel free. Doesn't really matter _how_ you reload the slider.